# Stuck on multiple table filtering query

Tags: sql, join

Ok so I will try to simplify the problem that I have.

I have 4 tables:

TableA:

```
OneID
```

TableB:

```
OneID (FK to TableA)
TwoID (FK to TableC)
```

TableC:

```
TwoID 
ThreeID (FK to TableD)
```

TableD:

```
ThreeID
```

I need a query to retrieve data from all 4 of these tables.

The query criteria is:

- want to inner join tables A, B, C
- want to join above result with table D with the following conditions:

  - if a record is in Table D but not in Table C, then it must always be present in the results
  - otherwise if a record is in Table D and Table C, then it should only be present if it is in the result of the A,B,C join

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: Fiddle created from the one Gareth provided: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e71b4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you have described is not really possible (or at least they are not really logical)

> if a record is in Table D but not in Table C, then it must always be present in the results

The only way a record could be "in Table D and not in Table C" is if the foreign key is null in table D, with no link from table D to tables A or B there is no other way you could define a record as being present in D and not in C:

> otherwise if a record is in Table D and Table C, then it should only be present if it is in the result of the A,B,C join

Again, the only way this could happen is with NULLABLE foreign keys. Regardless I think any of the below will get you the results you require:

```
SELECT  A.OneID, B.TwoID, c.ThreeID, D.FourID
FROM    D
        LEFT JOIN (C
        INNER JOIN B 
            ON B.TwoID = C.TwoID
        INNER JOIN A
            ON A.OneID = B.OneID)
            ON C.ThreeID = D.ThreeID;
```

Or

```
SELECT  A.OneID, B.TwoID, c.ThreeID, D.FourID
FROM    A
        INNER JOIN B
            ON B.OneID = A.OneID
        INNER JOIN C
            ON C.TwoID = B.TwoID
        RIGHT JOIN D
            ON D.ThreeID = C.ThreeID
```

Or

```
SELECT  A.OneID, B.TwoID, c.ThreeID, D.FourID
FROM    A
        INNER JOIN B
            ON B.OneID = A.OneID
        INNER JOIN C
            ON C.TwoID = B.TwoID
        INNER JOIN D
            ON D.ThreeID = C.ThreeID
UNION ALL
SELECT  NULL, NULL, NULL, FourID
FROM    D
WHERE   ThreeID IS NULL;
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24777/6)**

The first two have the same execution plan, it is just a matter of preference, I personally dislike using `RIGHT JOIN` because it makes queries feel like they in the wrong order i.e bottom to top, but this is purely my preference. The last query may perform better depending on the cardinality of your data and any indexes you have

---

**EDIT**

With your revised criteria I think the easiest way to implement this is with a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT  A.OneID, B.TwoID, c.ThreeID, d3 = D.ThreeID
FROM    A
        INNER JOIN B
            ON B.OneID = A.OneID
        INNER JOIN C
            ON C.TwoID = B.TwoID
        INNER JOIN D
            ON D.ThreeID = C.ThreeID
UNION ALL
SELECT  NULL, NULL, NULL, ThreeID
FROM    D
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE C.ThreeID = D.ThreeID);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e71b4/8)**

Comment: You're right I wrote FKs wrong, I am fixing them now

Comment: The second query is actually what I had as well.  However, it does not meet this condition: "if a record is in Table D and Table C, then it should only be present if it is in the result of the A,B,C join".  This query will actually include records in Table D which should be excluded.

Comment: As far as I can tell this still meets your requirements. Can you [edit this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d8239/3) with some sample data that illustrates which rows are being returned that shouldn't be or which rows aren't being returned that should be. Thanks

Comment: I edited the Fiddle with schemda, data, and comments.  Thanks

Comment: Can you post the revised link to the fiddle please.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understood you correctly but I will try to help anyway. It seems that you need to do `FULL OUTER JOIN` on table D:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    TableA AS A INNER JOIN 
    TableB AS B ON B.A_Id = A.Id INNER JOIN 
    TableC AS C ON C.B_Id = B.Id FULL OUTER JOIN 
    TableD AS D ON D.C_Id = C.Id
```

If I have misunderstood your requirements and you need more complicated criteria, you could just do `FULL OUTER JOIN` on all the tables and put extra conditions in `WHERE` part:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TableA AS A FULL OUTER JOIN 
    TableB AS B ON B.A_Id = A.Id FULL OUTER JOIN 
    TableC AS C ON C.B_Id = B.Id FULL OUTER JOIN 
    TableD AS D ON D.C_Id = C.Id

WHERE 
    --if a record is in Table D but not in Table C, then it must always be present in the results
    (D.Id IS NOT NULL AND C.Id IS NULL) OR
    (
        --otherwise if a record is in Table D and Table C, then it should only be present if it is in the result of the A,B,C join
        (D.Id IS NOT NULL AND C.Id IS NOT NULL) AND

        --want to inner join tables A, B, C
        (A.Id IS NOT NULL AND B.Id IS NOT NULL AND B.Id IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

Comment: This also has the same problem - will retrieve too many records